# "The semaphore timeout period has expired" error for USB connection

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb, semaphore, usbserial

I'm getting this error...

> The semaphore timeout period has expired.

On this line...

> ThePorts.ActivePort1.Open();

...but I only get it from time to time. When it happens, it happens over and over again. Then the problem goes away, for hours or days, then it comes back.

The serial port is a USB with a BlueTooth connected.

I think this guy was having a very similar problem, but not in C#

[Freeze on SerialPort.Open / DeviceIoControl / GetcommState with usbser.sys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749681/freeze-on-serialport-open-deviceiocontrol-getcommstate-with-usbser-sys?answertab=active#tab-top)

As best I can estimate, I have read his entire problem, and the resulting comments, and the answer, but I really can't figure out which one fixed his problem, or if C# is significantly different from what he was experiencing.

Thanks for any help for the clueless. This is the actual code where it's happening.

```
public static void Open_ActivePortWeWillUse(String Drone_StringNameFromUser)
{
    SerialPort TempSerialPort = new SerialPort(Drone_StringNameFromUser, (int) SerialPortSpeed);

    ThePorts.ActivePort1 = TempSerialPort;

    ThePorts.ActivePort1.DataBits = 8;
    ThePorts.ActivePort1.Parity = Parity.None;
    ThePorts.ActivePort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;

    ThePorts.ActivePort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OurBackGroundSerialPortReceiver);

    ThePorts.ActivePort1.Open();  // "Sometimes" Error hits here
}
```

Comment: It is a low-level Windows error, ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT, error code 121.  Highly specific to code that uses a semaphore.  The .NET SerialPort classes don't use a semaphore anywhere.  The Bluetooth driver you are using that emulates the serial port surely is using one, it is a common synchronization object used in native code.  Having these kind of problems with buggy drivers is not unusual.

Comment: In addition to previous comment: on the level you are working (.NET client) you cannot do anything with buggy serial port driver. In the post from your link, the real answer is in the comments: "The problem originated from a faulty firmware of the device".

Comment: Thank you Hans and Alex.  No clue if I found the answer, but I *THINK* this page [((eHow Page On Misbehaving USB hubs))](http://www.ehow.com/how_6813220_restart-usb-hub.html)  explains what to do. While that's not my favorite on the whole internet, if it got me the answer, then well; whatever.

Comment: Still okay after 3 hours. Should I post the answer ?

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I am now connecting without the semaphore timeout problem.

If anyone reading ever encounters the same thing, I hope that this procedure works for you; but no promises; hey, it's windows.

In my case this was Windows 7

I got a little hint from [This page](http://www.ehow.com/how_6813220_restart-usb-hub.html) on eHow; not sure if that might help anyone or not.

So anyway, this was the simple twenty three step procedure that worked for me

- Click on start button
- Choose Control Panel
- From Control Panel, choose Device Manger
- From Device Manager, choose Universal Serial Bus Controllers
- From Universal Serial Bus Controllers, click the little sideways triangle
- I cannot predict what you'll see on your computer, but on mine I get a long drop-down list
- Begin the investigation to figure out which one of these members of this list is the culprit...

  - On each member of the drop-down list, right-click on the name
  - A list will open, choose Properties
  - Guesswork time: using the various tabs near the top of the resulting window which opens, make a guess if this is the USB adapter driver which is choking your stuff with semaphore timeouts
- Once you have made the proper guess, then close the USB Root Hub Properties window (but leave the Device Manager window open).
- Physically disonnect anything and everything from that USB hub.
- Unplug it.
- Return your mouse pointer to that USB Root Hub in the list which you identified earlier.
- Right click again
- Choose Uninstall
- Let Windows do its thing
- Wait a little while
- Power Down the whole computer if you have the time; some say this is required. I think I got away without it.
- Plug the USB hub back into a USB connector on the PC
- If the list in the device manager blinks and does a few flash-bulbs, it's okay.
- Plug the BlueTooth connector back into the USB hub
- Let windows do its thing some more
- Within two minutes, I had a working COM port again, no semaphore timeouts.

Hope it works for anyone else who may be having a similar problem.

Comment: Nope, fixed again. Can anyone suggest what's going on ?

Comment: I got this when my VPN connection timed out. I just had to reconnect to correct it.

Comment: i disconnected my mouse and im unable to continue to do the final points you mentioned? :)

Comment: I have this error sometimes with Bluetooth Serial device (Microchip/Roving RN42 eval. kit), from the Bluetooth side (so the remote USB side is not involved). After one-two retries, the COM port usually opens and data can be sent. This is on Windows 10 1809, with in-box MS Bluetooth drivers. So it looks like artifact of the Bluetooth COM port emulation.

Answer (score 6):

This error could also appear if you are having network latency or internet or local network problems.  Bridged connections that have a failing counterpart may be the culprit as well.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well on two different Windows computers when communicating with a Arduino Leonardo. The reliable solution was:

- Find the COM port in device manager and open the device properties.
- Open the "Port Settings" tab, and click the advanced button.
- There, uncheck the box "Use FIFO buffers (required 16550 compatible UART), and press OK.

Unfortunately, I don't know what this feature does, or how it affects this issue. After several PC restarts and a dozen device connection cycles, this is the only thing that reliably fixed the issue.

Comment: Yep - had this writing one byte to a USB serial port.  Worked after 14 retries ;)


So just set the FIFO transmit buffer to 1 (i.e. disabled it)

Answer (score 0):

Too many big files all in one go. Windows barfs. Essentially the copying took too long because you asked too much of the computer and the file locking was locked too long and set a flag off, the flag is a semaphore error.

The computer stuffed itself and choked on it. I saw the RAM memory here get progressively filled with a Cache in RAM. Then when filled the subsystem ground to a halt with a semaphore error.

I have a workaround; copy or transfer fewer files not one humongous block. Break it down into sets of blocks and send across the files one at a time, maybe a few at a time, but not never the lot.

References:

https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired-0x80070079/

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21094630

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I solved by changing the Port Settings in the port driver (located in Ports in device manager) to fit the device I was using.

For me it was that wrong Bits per second value was set.

Answer (score 0):

I was this problem with program RealTerm, then I entered into device manager and just disable the Bluetooth device connected into the port COM3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your cable not with your code or connection some cables are designed to send power only some are designed to send power and data we have to see those types of cables