# The semaphore timeout period has expired exception when writing to virtual Serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb, cdc

I'm trying to communicate with USB device that uses CDC. The device connection is seen in Device Manager as Serial Port. I see the device and able to open the serial port. However, when I try to send a message to device, the **System.IO.IOException** is thrown saying:

> The semaphore timeout period has expired

I get the same exception with several third party C# Serial port terminal.

Using the same program with USB-RS232 Converter I'm able to communicate with another device with serial port (***not CDC***)

The CDC device manufacturer says that their module uses standard Windows CDC driver so the problem is on my end. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly SerialPort _serial = new SerialPort();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var portList = SerialPort.GetPortNames().ToList();
            _serial.PortName = portList[0]; 
            _serial.BaudRate = 9600;
            _serial.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            _serial.Parity = Parity.None;
            _serial.DataBits = 8;
            _serial.StopBits = StopBits.Two;
            _serial.ReadTimeout = 3000;
            _serial.WriteTimeout = 3000;
            _serial.DataReceived += ReceiveData;
            _serial.Open();
            
            while (true)
            {
                string str = Console.ReadLine();

                if (str.Equals("exit"))
                    return;
                SerialCmdSend(str);
            }
            
        }

        public static void SerialCmdSend(string data)
        {
            if (_serial.IsOpen)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] hexstring = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                    foreach (byte hexval in hexstring)
                    {
                        byte[] _hexval = { hexval };

                         // The exception is thrown 3 sec. after the first call of the Write function
                        _serial.Write(_hexval, 0, 1); 
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }


        private static void ReceiveData(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_serial.IsOpen)
            {
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                while (_serial.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    var b = _serial.ReadChar();
                    //Handle read data
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999439/the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired

Comment: Thanks. I tried this before posting the question.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible your USB device is checking if DTR (data terminal ready) is enabled before fully configuring a connection. I would suggest adding the following code to your c# program before opening your comport.

```
_serial.DtrEnable = true;
```