# Semaphore timeout period has expired error

Tags: c#, timeout, usb, serial-communication

I'm developing software to communicate with a board to send some parameters.

When I try to send some parameter to a device the program stops working, with the error message:

> The semaphore timeout period has expired

I've tried do some tutorials posted in stack overflow, and it is still not working.

PS: My device is data collector (tracker), so when I turn it on, the device start to sending data to my computer.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading; 
public class PortChat
{
static bool _continue;
static SerialPort _serialPort;



public static void Main()
{


    string name;
    string message;
    StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
    Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);

    // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
    _serialPort = new SerialPort();

    // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
    _serialPort.PortName = SetPortName(_serialPort.PortName);
    _serialPort.BaudRate = SetPortBaudRate(_serialPort.BaudRate);
    _serialPort.Parity = SetPortParity(_serialPort.Parity);
    _serialPort.DataBits = SetPortDataBits(_serialPort.DataBits);
    _serialPort.StopBits = SetPortStopBits(_serialPort.StopBits);
    _serialPort.Handshake = SetPortHandshake(_serialPort.Handshake);

    // Set the read/write timeouts
    _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
    _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

    _serialPort.Open();
    _continue = true;
    readThread.Start();

    Console.Write("Name: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Type QUIT to exit");

    while (_continue)
    {
        message = Console.ReadLine();

        if (stringComparer.Equals("quit", message))
        {
            _continue = false;
        }
        else
        {

            _serialPort.WriteLine(
                String.Format("<{0}>: {1}", name, message));
        }
    }

    readThread.Join();
    _serialPort.Close();
}



public async static void Read()
{
    while (_continue)
    {
        try
        {

            string message = _serialPort.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException) { }
    }
}

// Display Port values and prompt user to enter a port.
public static string SetPortName(string defaultPortName)
{
    string portName;

    Console.WriteLine("Available Ports:");
    foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
    }

    Console.Write("Enter COM port value (Default: {0}): ", defaultPortName);
    portName = Console.ReadLine();

    if (portName == "" || !(portName.ToLower()).StartsWith("com"))
    {
        portName = defaultPortName;
    }
    return portName;
}
// Display BaudRate values and prompt user to enter a value.
public static int SetPortBaudRate(int defaultPortBaudRate)
{
    string baudRate;

    Console.Write("Baud Rate(default:{0}): ", defaultPortBaudRate);
    baudRate = Console.ReadLine();

    if (baudRate == "")
    {
        baudRate = defaultPortBaudRate.ToString();
    }

    return int.Parse(baudRate);
}

// Display PortParity values and prompt user to enter a value.
public static Parity SetPortParity(Parity defaultPortParity)
{
    string parity;

    Console.WriteLine("Available Parity options:");
    foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Parity)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
    }

    Console.Write("Enter Parity value (Default: {0}):", defaultPortParity.ToString(), true);
    parity = Console.ReadLine();

    if (parity == "")
    {
        parity = defaultPortParity.ToString();
    }

    return (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), parity, true);
}
// Display DataBits values and prompt user to enter a value.
public static int SetPortDataBits(int defaultPortDataBits)
{
    string dataBits;

    Console.Write("Enter DataBits value (Default: {0}): ", defaultPortDataBits);
    dataBits = Console.ReadLine();

    if (dataBits == "")
    {
        dataBits = defaultPortDataBits.ToString();
    }

    return int.Parse(dataBits.ToUpperInvariant());
}

// Display StopBits values and prompt user to enter a value.
public static StopBits SetPortStopBits(StopBits defaultPortStopBits)
{
    string stopBits;

    Console.WriteLine("Available StopBits options:");
    foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(StopBits)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
    }

    Console.Write("Enter StopBits value (None is not supported and \n" +
     "raises an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. \n (Default: {0}):", defaultPortStopBits.ToString());
    stopBits = Console.ReadLine();

    if (stopBits == "")
    {
        stopBits = defaultPortStopBits.ToString();
    }

    return (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), stopBits, true);
}
public static Handshake SetPortHandshake(Handshake defaultPortHandshake)
{
    string handshake;

    Console.WriteLine("Available Handshake options:");
    foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Handshake)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
    }

    Console.Write("Enter Handshake value (Default: {0}):", defaultPortHandshake.ToString());
    handshake = Console.ReadLine();

    if (handshake == "")
    {
        handshake = defaultPortHandshake.ToString();
    }

    return (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), handshake, true);
}
}
```

I try follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999439/the-semaphore-timeout-period-has-expired) steps and but it not work for me!

Comment: It's not work for me! :(

Comment: Which Machine and OS are you using?